# How To Run Zend Guard Loader With Wampserver 2.2e (With PHP 5.3.x)

Tags: wamp, php-5.3, zend-guard

It's my polite and gentle request, if anybody knows the answer PLEASE share it with me, my concern is :-

I really want to run Zend Guard Loader with PHP 5.3.x and my current configuration is :-

Wampserver 2.2e
Apache 2.2.22
PHP 5.3.13
Mysql 5.5.24
Windows XP SP3

Everything is running fine and I tried my best to run Zend Guard Loader but couldn't. At last I checked Apache error log and found this error :-

"Cannot load Zend Guard Loader - it was built with configuration API220090626,NTS,VC9, whereas running engine is API220090626,TS,VC9"

That means Zend Guard Loader is non thread safe and current Apache is thread safe so how can we work around this issue? Is there a way to run Zend Guard Loader under Wamp using PHP 5.3.x

If you suggest me to shift to any other Wamp version or Apache version then I can do that in order to make some changes to run Zend Guard Loader with PHP 5.3.x

Thanks you so much in advance for being so nice to me.

Comment: Looks like you need to get a non-thread-safe version of PHP. http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/php-5.3.13-nts-Win32-VC9-x86.zip maybe? That directory is indexed, so you should be able to find the version you need if the one I linked is not what you want.

Comment: @sarah-kemp I'm afraid, Wampserver 2.2e (Apache 2.2.22 etc..) is thread safe so installing PHP (NTS) wouldn't work, as I already did all these experiments. Anyways thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, first go to this download page and choose the right NTS php pack for your system : http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/

Then go to this page and follow the instructions to set it in place : http://www.websanova.com/blog/php/manually-adding-php-versions-to-wamp#.Uvx9lPkhDdI

Best regards,
Jc.

Comment: WAMPServer would require the Thread Safe version (ts) not (nts)